# Check style error Assignmet of paramter not allowed

Tags: java

yes I know there is another question similar, but my issue is that my paramters are objects.

```
public void serStuff(OBJ x, OBJ y)

if (x== null)
{
    x = ANOTHER_VALUE;
}
if(y == null)
{
    y = ANOTHER_VALUE2;
}
```

so it doesnt like me assigning the paramters, but how would I fix this? would I just locally put another object

Comment: Are you sure the variables aren't going out of scope? This only changes their value within the function `serStuff`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix it is simply to stop assigning the parameters, since after returning from that method it has no effect anyway.

But sometimes it is still useful to do that, for example:

```
public void doSomething(String s){
    if (s == null){
        s = "";
    }
    s.callSomeMethodsAvoidingNullPointerException();
}
```

If you can't change the checkstyle config, you can just create another variable:

```
public void doSomething(String s){
    String sNotNull = s;
    if (sNotNull == null){
        sNotNull = "";
    }
    sNotNull.callSomeMethodsAvoidingNullPointerException();
}
```

This looks somehow clumsy. I would prefer changing the config if this pattern occurs often. But that might also be a very subjective view.

Comment: String is not `OBJ` i.e. it is immutable. OP might try to modify its field i.e use a field of the default object.

Comment: What do you mean by "String is not OBJ"? Of course, string is an object and behaves here like any other object. It might be immutable, but you can still assign a new value to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a local variable to check it. Like:

```
OBJ localX = (x == null) ? ANOTHER_VALUE : x;
```

Then process the new variable.

So you will make `localX` point to either the same object or the new `ANOTHER_VALUE`.

If you only need to check whether the given parameter is not null, you can also use `assert(x != null)`.

On the other hand, if sometimes you need to make sure you the parameter won't be changed, use `final`. This is (roughly!) the equivalent of the C `const`, the compiler "bites" you if you try to change it.